# Listing Sqoop jobs with details in terminal

Tags: hadoop, terminal, sqoop

Is there a way to list sqoop job's with for example their scheduled times from 9 am to 6 pm. Also, there's main jobs, in which there can be like 10 sqoop subjobs. Thanks in advance